# How to make call to number from text in textView?

Tags: android, textview, call

I need to make somethink like this: [image: iphone screenshot]

How can I select phone number with a blue color, and make on click listener on it?
I don't want to create other textView for it. I tried:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+" + tv.getText().toString().trim()));
    startActivity(callIntent);

}
```

Comment: attached image is output of your app, or you want to do like that?

Comment: I want somethink like that.

Comment: Please name the source of the image or create your own version. Also, I think a smaller one would be more convenient for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but you can set a link mask for a textview so that it automatically creates clickable links of phone numbers (or email addresses or urls...)
see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask(int)
This probably just opens the system's default action and you can't add a clicklistener, but maybe that's what you need...?

Comment: your answer is right, but it is the same as in previous answer)But you get plus)